# Modified distribution function that is $UC\big((0,1)\big)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Consider a real-valued random variable $X$  with distribution function $F$ and $V\sim UC\big((0,1)\big)$, which is independent of $X$. Define

$$\bar{F}(x,t):=P(X< x)+t P(X=x)=F(x-)+t\big[F(x)-F(x-)\big]$$

I want to show, that $\bar{F}(X,V)\sim UC\big((0,1)\big)$. So what I tried is following:

\begin{align}
\bar{F}(X,V)(\omega)&=P\big[X< X(\omega)\big]+V(\omega) P\big[X=X(\omega)\big]\\
&=P\big[X< X(\omega)\big]+P\big[V\le V(\omega)\big] P\big[X=X(\omega)\big]\\
&=P\big[X< X(\omega)\big]+P\big[V\le V(\omega)\cap X=X(\omega)\big]
\end{align}

Another try was this:

\begin{align}
\bar{F}(X,V)(\omega)&=(1-V(\omega))P\big[X<X(\omega)\big]+V(\omega)P\big[X=X(\omega)\big]\\
&=P\big[V>V(\omega)\big]P\big[X<X(\omega)\big]+P\big[V\le V(\omega)\big]P\big[X=X(\omega)\big]
\end{align}

But I do not know, where I should go from here. Of course the sets $\{X<X(\omega)\}$ and $\{X=X(\omega)\}$ are disjoint. Still I do not find a nice solution, if I take the union. Also I know that $1-V\sim UC\big((0,1)\big)$, which I should may use at some point. I would appreciate a hint. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your notation does not make sense. What is $\{X=X(\omega)\}$?

Comment: $\{X=X(\omega)\}=\{x\in\Omega: X(x)=X(\omega)\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u\in (0,1)$. If $F$ is continuous at $F^{-1}(u)$, then

\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(\bar{F}(X,V)\le u)&=\mathsf{P}(\bar{F}(X,V)\le u,X\le F^{-1}(u)) \\
&\quad+\mathsf{P}(\bar{F}(X,V)\le u,X> F^{-1}(u)) \\
&=\mathsf{P}(X\le F^{-1}(u))=F(F^{-1}(u))=u.
\end{align}

If $F$ has a jump at $F^{-1}(u)$, then, letting $a:=\mathsf{P}(X<F^{-1}(u))$ and $b:=\mathsf{P}(X\le F^{-1}(u))$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(\bar{F}(X,V)\le u)&=\mathsf{P}(\bar{F}(X,V)\le u, X< F^{-1}(u)) \\
&\quad+\mathsf{P}(\bar{F}(X,V)\le u,X=F^{-1}(u)) \\
&=a+(u-a)=u
\end{align}
because
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{P}((1-V)F(X-)+VF(X)\le u,X=F^{-1}(u)) \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{P}((1-V)a+Vb\le u)\mathsf{P}(X=F^{-1}(u))=\frac{u-a}{b-a}\times (b-a).
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, thanks already for your good answer. I have a last question. If $F$ has a jump at $F^{-1}(u)$ how do I find, that $\{\bar{F}(X,V)\le u\}\cap\{X>F^{-1}(u)\}=\emptyset$?

Comment: First, suppose that $u<b$. Then $F(X-)\ge F(F^{-1}(u))\ge b>u$ and $\bar{F}(X,V)> u$ on $\{X>F^{-1}(u)\}$. If $u=b$, the intersection may be nonempty. However,
$$
\mathsf{P}(\bar{F}(X,V)\le u,X>F^{-1}(u))=0.
$$

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you very much!